# jquery ajax only returning 1 result

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsonp, feed, blogger

### Fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/4BKzd/7/

i have the below jquery - the problem i am having is that it only returns 1 image src when i have specified for 3 to be returned `&max-results=3` i conjured up the jquery from this post if you [require reference](http://www.threelas.com/2012/02/basic-blogger-json-feed-api.html)

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://www.blogger.com/feeds/1570527947646221682/posts/default?alt=json-in-script&max-results=3&rel=alternate',
    type: 'get',
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function(data){
        for (var i = 0; i < data.feed.entry.length; i++){
            for (var j=0; j < data.feed.entry[i].link.length; j++){
                if (data.feed.entry[i].link[j].rel == 'alternate'){
                 var img = data.feed.entry[i].media$thumbnail.url;
                    break;
                }
            }
            $('div.elem').append(img);           
        }
    }
});​
```

Comment: Look in the console and see what result is returned from the ajax request. The problem could be in your javascript or server-side script...

Comment: +1 just checked.. didn't think to sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the given code I get 3 entries.

But I get only 2 images, because in the 3rd entry is no media$thumbnail , what will force an error.

So you first need to check if **`data.feed.entry[i].media$thumbnail`** exists before you try to access **`data.feed.entry[i].media$thumbnail.url`**